# Elementary Proof of No Odd Perfect Numbers

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

I came across [this proof](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.07176.pdf) on the Arxiv that there are no odd perfect numbers. It is elementary and easy to follow and looks correct to me? Of course there must be a mistake there somewhere but I am not catching it - could someone else take a look?

Comment: Here are some things to watch out. The author of this paper has no PhD in mathematics. Of course, that is not proof that it is wrong, but a gigantic red flag. Second, the author cites "popular math" papers, which no serious mathematical paper ever does. Third, the author states, "The sum of divisors of 1 is 1, which is not two times.". This is such a trivial observation that it again suggests that this is not a serious paper. Imagine solving a longstanding problem in number theory and telling your readers that the sum of divisors of 1 is equal to 1. But I hope I am wrong about the author.

Comment: Galois also had no PhD in mathematics. And Euclid too. Popular math papers are cited quite often. Say, Conway's paper in the Monthly.

Comment: Another possible red flag is that the paper was released on *April Fools' Day*.  Additionally, the paper is in the **math.GM** (General Mathematics) subject area of arXiv rather than the **math.NT** (Number Theory) subject area.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I wasted anyone's time, I listed the error below

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki:  I don't think having no PhD in Mathematics counts as a red flag.  (See the comment by @MarkVSapir.)

Comment: It's good that you found the error yourself, but asking about claimed solutions to open conjectures is off-topic for Math SE.

Comment: @markvs The comment on Galois not having a PhD is not a good point. Galois wrote his work during a revolution in the early 1800s. Academic math PhDs were not as common as they are today. There are virtually no big open problems solved by those outside of the math PhD world anymore. The only exception I can currently think of is Aubrey de Grey. But even him had a PhD in a different area of science.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki: I do not know who Aubrey de Grey is. There are several  recent examples. Probably the most famous is Andrew Casson from Yale. Israel Gelfand had a PhD, but he did not have a high school diploma or a BS. Still even before he got his PhD (under the guidance of Kolmogorov) he was stronger than most users of SE combined. Joan Birman also got her PhD at relatively old age, but of course she was a great mathematician anyway.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki the first version was in January - https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.07176v1.pdf.

Comment: @Cornifer:  I am, of course, referring to the most recent version of the paper on arXiv - https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.07176v2.pdf

Answer (score 8):

I see (3.6) is wrong:

> The third term, $\prod _{i=1} ^ m p_i \sigma (p_i ^ {a_i-1})$ is as
> one expects, the rest. It includes those divisors that have at least
> one $p_1$ but also include some other prime or primes.

I don't think this is right, there's no way from this we could get, say, $p_1p_2$ (with $m \ge 3$) since $p_3$ is always in the product.